# What are the criteria for a tag creator's userid to be shown or not?

Tags: support, bug, display-names, tag-creation

Consider these Tag info pages:

- the [Tag info page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bounty/info) for the [bounty](/questions/tagged/bounty) tag.
- the [Tag info page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/markdown/info) for the [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) tag.

For either of these 2 pages, in the right column, it shows the typical **Stats** for each tag, i.e:

- Created.
- Viewed.
- Active.
- Editors.

But, have a closer look at the "*Created*" part of those stats on the Tag info page:

- for the [bounty](/questions/tagged/bounty) tag, it includes a link to the userid who created it.
- for the [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) tag, it does not includes such link to the userid who created it.

**My question**: What's the logic to yes or no include such link to the userid who create a tag?

PS: the 2 tags in my question are pretty much random picked: here on meta.SE there are plenty of tags like [bounty](/questions/tagged/bounty),  while there are also plenty of tags like [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown). Moreover, I've noticed similar cases in various other SE sites. Here are a few of them (from Drupal.SE):

- similar to [bounty](/questions/tagged/bounty): [group](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/group/info) and [rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/rules/info)
- similar to [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown): [forena](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/forena/info) and [flags](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/flags/info)

Comment: It's even deeper. Two more bugs: the time in "Created" is wrong, showing the time when the site was created, while the tooltip is correct. And even worse, the "Created by" in the [tag:bounty] tag is wrong, that user never even edited the tag wiki. No idea how his name appears there. There are probably several very old bugs here.

Comment: [cont] The [first revision of the bounty tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2083), which actually created it, was suggested by [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155190/benny) and approved by [this other user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1782/juan). Neither of those are listed as the tag creators.

Comment: Bonjour @ShadowWizard ! Interested **additional** discoveries in your (first) comment. Though I don't quiet understand (yet) what you mean, ie WHERE you see that "time". **But**: could it be that you're misinterpreting things (sorry to doubt ...). I.e. it's one thing to CREATE a tag (eg: empty at the very start), and another thing to either create a tag wiki or tag wiki excerpt. Or am I still missing something in your previous comment(s)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard but the tag itself was indeed [created by VonC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/9/revisions), as the tag page says: _8 years, 7 months ago by VonC_.

Comment: @fedorqui oh, the first question with the tag... right. So the tooltip is wrong, showing the time of the first tag **edit**. Meh, it's all super confusing.

Comment: To sum things up: there is a mix between **tag** creation, and **tag wiki** creation, as when tag is created, it's created with empty wiki, which is later edited. So part of the stats are about the first edit, and some about the tag itself, not the wiki.

Comment: @Shadow I think it is more reasonable to keep track of who created the tag instead of who created the wiki page of the tag, and this seems to be what is implemented right now. But yes, since it later on says _editors_ then this part is about the wiki page itself :S

Comment: @Sha the mixed up date tooltip is probably due to this only being half fixed: ["created" date and user displayed on tag wiki refer to different events](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/250398) (i.e. they fixed the shown date but forgot the tooltip)

Comment: @ShadowWizard : Regarding *the time in "Created" is wrong, showing the time when the site was created, while the tooltip is correct*, there is already a [bug reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297857/312043) by me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Show a tag's creator on the tag wiki page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108239/307988):

> If a tag has a related [Taxonomist badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist), the creator will now be shown on its tag wiki/info page.

So the creator is taken from the owner of the taxonomist badge associated with that tag. If there is no taxonomist badge (e.g. the tag has less than 50 questions) or no user with that badge (e.g. if the user no longer exists) then a creator won't be shown.

Note that tags are only created once; if a tag is deleted (e.g. removed from all questions and automatically removed from the system) then recreated at a later date, the original creator of the tag is still the "creator" of the tag (see e.g. [Taxonomist Badge - Who's the owner?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232143/307988))

---

If we go through the tags you listed...

- [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bounty/info): VonC is listed as the creator and [has the taxonomist badge for that tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=6309)
- [markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/markdown/info): The user [no longer exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28271/307988)
- [group](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/group/info): Adrian Cid Almaguer is listed as the creator and [has the taxonomist badge for that tag](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=28275)
- [rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/rules/info): Gargoyle is listed as the creator and [has the taxonomist badge for that tag](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=81)
- [forena](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/forena/info) only has 26 questions (so no taxonomist has been awarded yet)

The only anomaly is...

- [flags](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/flags/info). No creator is listed, but you can see from the list of badges that no taxonomist has been awarded for that tag: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist so the anomoly is why no taxonomist was awarded; not why no creator is listed.

Comment: Interesting answer. I need more time to "digest" it, but if this would be the correct answer, then how would that explain the current situation for the [flags](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/flags/info) tag (on Drupal.SE) ... with current 421 questions using this tag ... but NO userid mentioned?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens see my update, there is no taxonomist badge for that tag. Not sure why that is, but that is why no creator is listed

Comment: Hey @Cai, your answer definitely goes in the right direction (= part of the puzzle?). But could it be that this taxonomist-related logic applies to cases where "at first" (when the tag was created) there is no userid mentioned (due to the lack of privilege, as in my own answer). And if later on a taxonomist user appears, then (and only then) it gets added. But then what happens if (eg) some day a taxonomist appears for a tag that already had (from the beginning) a userid mentioned. Eg for group tag: would a group-taxonomist then REPLACE username "adrian"?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens you're thinking too much about it.... if there is a taxonomist that user is shown, if there isn't then nothing is shown, it's as simple as that. (unless you've got an example that shows otherwise, which I don't see)

Comment: Regarding the [flags](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/flags/info) tag, it looks like [it was introduced on Apr 10'11](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/2097/revisions) by a user that [got the Taxonomist badge](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=199) a bit later for another, unknown, tag. Since the Taxonomist badge is awarded just once, counting on its information to track the creator seems quite buggy.

Comment: OK, with the additional comment from @fedorqui here, it seems that this answer is, pretty sure, the explanation for what my question is about. I did some extra checking for other tags, and cannot find any contradiction of this. So until further notice (cfr "unless you've got an example that shows otherwise ..."), I'm going to mark this as accepted ...

Comment: Just in case anybody is looking for a similar case like the "flags" tag ... The "[8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/8/info)" (currently used in "only" 9270 questions ...) seems to suffer a similar issue. Same kind of bug, or yet another variation?

Comment: @Pierre the tag was created by a user that no longer exists: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/7209/1  ...as fedorqui said, taxonomist just isn't a very good way to determine who created a tag, there will be countless tags with no creator listed

Comment: @Cai merci for that clarification also. and I fully agree with you on that ... PS: from now on I'll think twice when I see somewhere "created", similar to when I see "deleted" of something (BTW: DELETE does not exist in any SE site, it is only a synonym for "hidden from low rep users ...").

Answer (score 2):

I think this all has to do with the migration from MSO to MSE. They created a whole new site and imported (some of) the data from MSO.

There seems there are more problems. The creator of the [bounty](/questions/tagged/bounty) tag should be [Benny](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155190/benny), according to SEDE (`select wikipostid from tags where tagname = 'bounty'` = 78196, `select owneruserid, ownerdisplayname from posts where id = 78196` = 155190, which is Benny. Display name is empty).

The [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) tag seems to check out fine. It is attributed to the Community, which seems reasonable given the background.

On Stack Overflow, the C# tag misses a creator, which has to be Jon Skeet given SEDE (`select owneruserid, ownerdisplayname from posts where id = 3607007` yields '22656' and again an empty display name). Maybe this column was added later and not filled in correctly for old posts?

Comment: ohh... the migration... but still, how come VonC is there?

Comment: I have no clue. Some messed up migration script? @Sha

Comment: There might be different reasons for different tags. This one seems the most plausible for MSE @Pierre.Vriens

Comment: @PatrickHofman well, turns out VonC asked the first question having that tag, thus creating it. But somehow it's not reflected in other places where it should be.

Comment: You mean, the first question or the first question that was migrated? @Sha

Comment: First question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/how-about-a-separate-private-bounty-points-alongside-your-public-reputation).

Comment: Please review the additional examples I added in my PS. IMO it proofs that the very first phrase of this answer cannot be the explanation.